# Query based on multiple filters in Firebase

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-design

I am working out the structure for a JSON database for an app like onlyFans. Basically, someone can create a club, then inside of that club, there are sections where the creator's posts are shown and another where the club members posts are shown. There is however a filter option where ***both can be seen***.

In order to make option 1 below work, I need to be able to filter based on if `isFromCreator=true` and at the same time based on timstamp. How can I do this?

Here are the 2 I have written down:

```
ClubContent
     CreatorID
         clubID
            postID: {isFromCreator: Bool}
         OR
            creatorPosts
              postID: {}
            MemeberPosts
              postID: {}
```

---

Something like the below would be what I want:

```
ref.child("Content").child("jhTFin5npXeOv2fdwHBrTxTdWIi2").child("1622325513718")
            .queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")
            .queryLimited(toLast: 10)
            .queryEqual(toValue: true, childKey: "isFromCreator")
```

I tried`queryEqual` yet it did not return any of the values I know exist with the configuration I specified.

Answer (score -1):

You can use additional resource locations within rules by referencing the parent/child directories specifically and comparing the `val()` of the respective node structure.

for example:
`".write": "data.parent().child('postID').child('isFromCreator').val()"`

Just be aware that Security Rules do not filter or process the data in the request, only allow or deny the requested operation.

You can read more about this from the relevant documentation:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#referencing_data_in_other_paths
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#rules-not-filters